# div height 100% with content

Tags: html, css

Would I like to know how I can put in a div 100% height?
I have a div with an image and a div with content.

The image has a width 100%, and the same content but does not fill the entire image div.

I copied the code if you can help.

Thank you,

```css
#carta div{
 position: relative;
 display: table;
}

#carta div .overlay{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition:all .4s ease-out;
   transition:all .4s ease-out;
}

#carta .overlay:hover{
 opacity: 1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#carta .col-1-4{
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;
 
}


#carta div img{
 width: 100%;
 display: table;
}

#carta .overlay p{
 font-style: oblique;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-top: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 border-top: 1px solid white;
 -webkit-transition:all .4s ease-out;
   transition:all .4s ease-out;
}

#carta .overlay h5{
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 50px;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="clearFix">
   <div class="col-1-4">
    <img src="img/carta/atun.jpg" alt="atún revuelto"/>
    <div class="overlay">
     <h5>Atun revuelto</h5>
     <p>15€</p>
    </div>
    
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-1-4">
    <img src="img/carta/especialidaditaliana.jpg" alt="especialidad italiana"/>
    <div class="overlay">
     <h5>Especialidad Italiana</h5>
     <p>15€</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you will try the set the height of container div to 100% of the browser window using "height:100%;" it doesn't work, because the percentage (%) is a relative unit so the resulting height is depends on the height of parent element's height.
The container div has 1 parent element: .col-1-4 (according to the  code), so if you also set the height of .col-1-4 to 100% the resulting height of overlay div becomes equal the 100% height of the browser window.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could include the dimensions of the `<img>`s in your `CSS` above. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

I want to adjust the height of the <div class = "overlay"> what occupies the div with the image (400 x 400px).

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `background` in css,
something like this: `background: url(img/carta/especialidaditaliana.jpg);`

You also can use `div` to set background
Like this: `<div class="img">content</div>` but you also need css `background`.

Something like this?
It should work in .html document...

```html
<style>
.img {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://goo.gl/ytbJn8);
  color: white;
}
</style>
<div class="img">This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text.</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how setting a background image helps answer the question of how to set a div's height.  You might want to re-read the question.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your responses.

I have solved by adding "display: table-cell" in the css class ".overlay"

Thus occupies the div, which occupies the image.

Many thanks